# Android 4.2.2 Device Offline

Tags: android, adb, offline, device

I've read several users having similar problems, but none of the solutions I've found have solved my issue.

I have several Nexus devices running Android 4.2.2 and they all show up as offline and none of them show a prompt when I plug them in.

I already tried:

- unplugging/plugging them in
- switching off/on usb debugging
- restarting computer, nexus devices and the adb server
- reinstalling drivers and even switching drivers to Samsung ADB drivers
- Confirmed I'm running adb 1.0.31
- Made sure my path points to adb.exe
- Deleted any old adb.exe files on my entire computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer. I had installed "SnapPea", which apparently ships its own ADB.exe. It was somehow getting in the way. Uninstalling this poorly written software and rebooting fixed the issue.

As an Android developer, this type of thing is scary. Was it sending everything I did to a home server somewhere? Why should any software install ADB on a customer's computer?

This is probably the reason Google had to add this security measure in the first place...

Comment: Just  kill the SnapPea Process and use the default ADB.Lots of Android Device Manager from China use the manager's own adb client to connect with the android device.

Answer (score 35):

if you have properly installed adb and you tried all of the remedies mentioned at above the listen to my remedy:

The reason to appearing "device offline" in android 4.2.2 is that android has a security feature in 4.2.2 that create a whitelist of usb ports that can be used as debugging port.

After plugging deivce in usb and entering the command "adb devices" a popup window will be raised in your device and ask you to accept the connection:

[image: popup window to accept RSA fingerprint of your usb]

After accepting RSA fingerprint of you usb you can now issue the "adb devices" again and see the device is no longer offline,

If you dont see the popup window, the reason is your adb version is old, your adb version must ne at least 1.0.31 (you can see the version using the command "adb version"). if version is older than 1.0.31 then update your platform-tools package using latest updates from google. You can find the latest version in [sdk-repository](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml). find **platform-tools*.zip** associated with your OS and download from  `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools*.zip` .

for example version 19.0.1 of platform-tools can be downloaded using these links:

For linux: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip

For windows: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r19.0.1-windows.zip

For MacOSx: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r19.0.1-macosx.zip

that's it

Comment: Thank you! After trying several non-working solutions this one finally solved my problem.

Comment: @sarigalin, I don't have time to edit the answer (maybe someone has some ;), just want to add that if you always want the latest version, search for "platform-tools*zip" in http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml (found it by searching for "site:dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository platform tools")

Comment: Thanks @CostinGușă. I edited answer and updated according to your comment

Comment: It's still not doing it on mine.  I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 8.2.  It just keeps saying it's offline.  Is there something else I can try?  Thanks!

Comment: I have adb 1.0.31 (on Ubuntu). Device still says offline in `adb devices` and no popup window shows on the phone. Is there something else?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and it was just my ADT Eclipse plugin wich was out of date.
I install all the updates and everything went ok. 
I don't know if its the same for you, sometimes we just forgot to put the updates...

Comment: Thanks. I had the updates as stated in the question. It was just that SnapPea was interfering.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was working, but a minute later (upon reconnecting the usb cable) the device was 'offline'. I got it 'online' again by disabling and then re-enabling the USB Debugging option in the developer settings of the device.