# Debugging native (c/c++) code in Android with DS-5

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, arm, ds-5

I'm trying to debug an Android project that has native code with the ARM development studio but I can't make it to work.

I tried all kind of tutorials and other online help I could find but when I try to debug it just won't work.

I then decided to try a simple example instead of my (more) complicated project just to firstly get the debugger going but even that fails.
I'm using this tutorial: [Loading the hello-neon application on to an Android target](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0478j/CIHEEGJH.html) (except that I want to run it on a real device).
I followed all of the steps but when I finally try to debug I get this message:

> Unable to connect to Hello Neon Example.
>
> Reason:
>
> The script file ( push_pull.py ) failed during execution:
>
> Timeout error checking adb connection
>
> See Target Console view for more details

The "Target Console" is empty and offers no more details.

I'm working with eclipse (Juno release 2) on a linux machine (64bit Mint 12) and NDK r8e.
The device I'm trying to run the project on is a Samsun S2 (android 4.1.2).

Any ideas why this happens?
Thanks.

Comment: For another guide to Android native app debug in DS-5, try the following link, hopefully it will help: [DS-5 Android native app debug tutorial](http://ds.arm.com/developer-resources/tutorials/android-native-app-debug-tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem. But there was no any problem with debuging native part of app a month or two earlier.It worked perfectly. I'm very confused, but in process of solving this issue. First of all look if there is a "gdbserver"-file in folder "Binaries" (C/C++ perspective)? And the second thing: I think that there is a problem with ADB-connection. I've tried variouse devices (Sony Xperia and two rooged tabs, small and big produced by HTC) and variouse OS (OS x mavericks eclipse kepler with ARM and Android plugins and Ubuntu 12.04 DS-5 CE with android plugin); here is the result: debuging started only on big HTC on Mac, because when i plug HTC only, DS-5 perspective start to resive a device info in DS Debug config in frame "connections" where you choose a device (Device information:API leven, etc., **Root access available**) maybe the problem is in **root access**....

Continue solving...

Here is the solve. In your ds-5 debug configuration check up your device (in "connections" panel), compair it's ser.No. with that number that you can get when exec command "adb devices" (device must be connected, offcourse). If there is no device in list check up your JRE, it must be from Oracle, and installed like mentioned here this link has taken from here. then restart eclipse (or OS) If that not help copy adb from android-sdk dir to /bin/ or export $PATH (in my case i've got an exportation< but needed to copy adb). If device appear in list - thats good)))) select it and look for "device information"...And here is the very important point - there must be a root access to it!!!

And here is one practical advise: start your DS-5 from terminal, to see what's going on with it.

Comment: I think you should structure this more as an answer to the question than as an history of your personal experience

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your device is not connected,
try "adb devices" to list your device
if you saw some device listed as offline, resolve this by the following post:
[Android 4.2.2 Device Offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079211/android-4-2-2-device-offline)

Comment: No, that's not the problem, this is not a typical "i can't view my android device in the target devices list" problem, this was a DS-5 problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solve. In your ds-5 debug configuration check up your device (in "connections" panel), compair it's ser.No. with that number that you can get when exec command "adb devices" (device must be connected, offcourse). If there is no device in list check up your JRE, it must be from Oracle, and installed like mentioned [here](http://www.64bitjungle.com/ubuntu/install-java-jre-160-update-x-on-hardy-as-the-default-java-runtime/) this link has taken from [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation). then restart eclipse (or OS) If that not help copy **adb** from android-sdk dir to /bin/ or export $PATH (in my case i've got an exportation< but needed to copy adb). If device appear in list - thats good)))) select it and look for "device information"...And here is the very important point - **there must be a root access to it**!!!

And here is one practical advise: start your DS-5 from terminal, to see what's going on with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me...

Remove all devices except the device you'll work on

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ adb root
adbd is already running as root
```